# Swap two values in string(s) and sort by second value in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have string like this:

```
EUR-USD,USD-EUR,SEk-CAD
```

I want to make this to an array and sort by second currency and I want to the result to be

```
SEk-CAD,USD-EUR,EUR-USD
```

(Sorted by CAD, EUR and USD)

This is my attempt and it works, but I'm wondering if I'm not "overdoing" this? Anyone has an easier/better solution to achieve this?

**Second currency**

Create an array of currency pairs:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'EUR' (length=3)
      1 => string 'USD' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'USD' (length=3)
      1 => string 'EUR' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'SEk' (length=3)
      1 => string 'CAD' (length=3)
```

Reverse order of currencies pairs in above array and put them into a non mutlidimensional array:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'USD-EUR' (length=7)
  1 => string 'EUR-USD' (length=7)
  2 => string 'CAD-SEk' (length=7)
```

Sort the array (with `sort()` ) and glue that array into a new string

```
string 'CAD-SEk,EUR-USD,USD-EUR' (length=23)
```

Make an array of currency pairs from the newly created string:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'CAD' (length=3)
      1 => string 'SEk' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'EUR' (length=3)
      1 => string 'USD' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'USD' (length=3)
      1 => string 'EUR' (length=3)
```

Reverse order of currencies pairs in above array and put them into a non mutlidimensional array:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'SEk-CAD' (length=7)
  1 => string 'USD-EUR' (length=7)
  2 => string 'EUR-USD' (length=7)
```

Glue the array together into a final string:

```
string 'SEk-CAD,USD-EUR,EUR-USD' (length=23)
```

Comment: take help from [sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$currency_string = "EUR-USD,USD-EUR,SEk-CAD";

$currency_array = explode(",", $currency_string);

function compare($a, $b) {

    $a = explode("-", $a);
    $b = explode("-", $b);

    if ($a[1] === $b[1]){
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a[1] < $b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
 }

 usort($currency_array, "compare");

 $final_currency_string = implode(",", $currency_array);

 echo $final_currency_string; // Prints SEk-CAD,USD-EUR,EUR-USD
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think I've got a shorter and a better approach. Let me edit my answer. :)